# Parsing multiple custom properties from Application.Properties value in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to creating custom conditions in my spring application.properties file. My custom conditions are as follows

> application_property_1=true
>
> application_property_2=false

I am trying to use these properties in various parts of my application. One way is to use Condition...but I am am able to parse only one of the properties at a time through one class ...

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;

public class TestConditionImpl implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String enabled = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("application_property_1");
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(enabled);

    }
}
```

I understand, I can create another class which implements the Condition class to parse the application_property_2 value.

I am looking for a simpler way instead of trying to create a new class for each property.

Comment: what happens if you  use other property? like `context.getEnvironment().getProperty("application_property_2");`

Comment: creation is not the problem - only one return is possible inside this and that is the constraint.

Comment: you should edit your question and highlight that. No where in your question it is mentioned about returning. It just talks about parsing

Comment: Returning is happening inside a particular implementation I am doing. What i want to do is use the fields in the application.properties and hence the word according to me parse. If you have a better word, will incorporate. Return is not, however, the correct word.

Comment: I don't know what is it that you expect. I said returning because you mentioned it in your comment `only one return is possible`

Comment: No problem. People who have done this before will know what is expected.

Comment: Why not to keep a property name as an instance variable and instantiate it via constructor?

Comment: @CaptainHackSparrow 
I think you are interested in Spring profiling, so depending on your current profile, spring will automatically select one of the properties defined for given profile. Do you want this? For exp: prop_1_test1 = value1 & prop_1_test2 = value2. where "test1" & "test2" are your profiles. So now if your current profile is "test2", then spring will select value of "prop_1_test2" and vice versa